# R data.frame to SQL - preserving ordered factors

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rmysql, factors

I am just starting to use MySQL to handle data that is currently in R dataframe objects.  I was hoping for a simple round-trip to and from SQL that would recreate an R dataframe exactly:

```
library("compare",pos=2)
library("RMySQL",pos=2)
conR <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
             user = '...',
             password = '...',
             host = '...',
             dbname='r2014')
a3 <- data.frame(x=5:1,y=letters[1:5],z=ordered(c("NEVER","ALWAYS","NEVER","SOMETIMES","NEVER"),levels=c("NEVER","SOMETIMES","ALWAYS")))
a3
dbWriteTable(conn = conR, name = 'a3', value = a3)
a4 <- dbReadTable(conn = conR, name = 'a3')
compare(a3,a4)$detailedResult
a3$z
a4$z
```

the result shows that factors end up as strings (columns y and z), and that the ordering information for ordered factors is lost (column z):

```
> a3
  x y         z
1 5 a     NEVER
2 4 b    ALWAYS
3 3 c     NEVER
4 2 d SOMETIMES
5 1 e     NEVER
> compare(a3,a4)$detailedResult
    x     y     z 
  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
> a3$z
[1] NEVER     ALWAYS    NEVER     SOMETIMES NEVER    
Levels: NEVER < SOMETIMES < ALWAYS
> a4$z
[1] "NEVER"     "ALWAYS"    "NEVER"     "SOMETIMES" "NEVER" 
> a3$y
[1] a b c d e
Levels: a b c d e
> a4$y
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Is there some way to specify the information in the ordered factors in the creation of the table a3 in the database?

Comment: In a relational database, tables represent *unordered* sets.  You cannot depend on the ordering of results returned by a query unless you explicitly use `order by` in the outermost `select` for the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the issue is not in the query results, it is that the R data.frame object stores information about levels for a factor, which other functions in R understand.  I was hoping to have this information transferred to the table that dbWriteTable creates, and then be preserved when dbReadTable reads the data.frame back into R.

Comment: I don't think a relational db can represent the ordering easily in the same table.  I would suggest creating another table to represent the ordering.  It would have two columns: the factor label and the rank of the label in the ordering.

Comment: There's currently no way to seamlessly round trip factors (ordered or otherwise) back and forth to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code to:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = conR, name = 'a3', value = a3, row.names=TRUE)
a4 <- dbReadTable(conn = conR, name = 'a3', row.names=TRUE)
```

`row.names` of a data.frame are ordered by default. When they are stored in an SQL column they are also ordered. The `SELECT` query can use `ORDER BY row_names` to fetch the ordered set.

Value of `row.names` in `dbReadTable()` argument can be changed to `NA` in case the SQL table does not contain the `row_names` column.[2]

[1] **REF: `DBI::dbWriteTable`**

> ```
>  The interpretation of rownames depends on the ‘row.names’
>  argument, see ‘sqlRownamesToColumn()’ for details:
>
>     • If ‘FALSE’ or ‘NULL’, row names are ignored.
>
>     • If ‘TRUE’, row names are converted to a column named
>       "row_names", even if the input data frame only has natural
>       row names from 1 to ‘nrow(...)’.
>
>     • If ‘NA’, a column named "row_names" is created if the data
>       has custom row names, no extra column is created in the case
>       of natural row names.
>
>     • If a string, this specifies the name of the column in the
>       remote table that contains the row names, even if the input
>       data frame only has natural row names.
> ```

[2] **REF: `DBI::dbReadTable`**

> ```
>  The presence of rownames depends on the ‘row.names’ argument, see
>  ‘sqlColumnToRownames()’ for details:
>
>     • If ‘FALSE’ or ‘NULL’, the returned data frame doesn't have
>       row names.
>
>     • If ‘TRUE’, a column named "row_names" is converted to row
>       names.
>
>     • If ‘NA’, a column named "row_names" is converted to row names
>       if it exists, otherwise no translation occurs.
>
>     • If a string, this specifies the name of the column in the
>       remote table that contains the row names.
> ```